# Multiclass partition function for ruby array/list

Tags: ruby, dictionary, filter, functional-programming, reduce

I have just gotten deeper into functional aspects of ruby and are fiddling with map/reduce and some filtering.

I have now gotten to a point where I have a list of items of the following structure:

```
{:price=>100.0, :size=>'small', :description=>'some description'}
```

The value for `:size` may be one of `['small', 'medium', 'large']`.

Is there a way to partition the whole list into sublists with only those elements which are of size small, medium and large without setting up a filter function for each of these values?

Basically I am asking wether there is some multiclass Array.partition.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`Enumberable#group_by`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by):

```
list = [
  {:price=>100.0, :size=>'small', :description=>'some description'},
  {:price=>123.0, :size=>'small', :description=>'some description 2'},
  {:price=>456.0, :size=>'medium', :description=>'some description 3'}
]

list.group_by {|item| item[:size]}
  # => {
  #      "small" => [
  #        {:price=>100.0, :size=>"small", :description=>"some description"},
  #        {:price=>123.0, :size=>"small", :description=>"some description 2"}
  #      ],
  #      "medium" => [
  #        {:price=>456.0, :size=>"medium", :description=>"some description 3"}
  #      ]
  #    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: @Minato you might want to use a proper class for your list items with accessor methods for `price`, `size`, and `description`. That would allow you to write `group_by(&:size)`.

Comment: Nice to know! But I will stay with the hash for now as this form is just one of multiple forms the list items take, due to multiple transformations that are involved.

Answer (score 3):

```
input = [
  {:price=>100.0, :size=>'small', :description=>'some description 1'},
  {:price=>100.0, :size=>'large', :description=>'some description 2'},
  {:price=>100.0, :size=>'small', :description=>'some description 3'},
  {:price=>100.0, :size=>'large', :description=>'some description 4'},
  {:price=>100.0, :size=>'small', :description=>'some description 5'},
  {:price=>100.0, :size=>'small', :description=>'some description 6'}
]

input.group_by { |e| e[:size] }
```

---

Whether you consider the result should not contain the size in hashes, use `Hash#delete` to mutate elements:

```
input.group_by { |e| e.delete :size }
#⇒ {
#  "large" => [
#    [0] {
#      :description => "some description 2",
#            :price => 100.0
#    },
#    [1] {
#      :description => "some description 4",
#            :price => 100.0
#    }
#  ],
#  "small" => [
#    [0] {
#      :description => "some description 1",
#            :price => 100.0
#    },
#    [1] {
#      :description => "some description 3",
#            :price => 100.0
#    },
#    [2] {
#      :description => "some description 5",
#            :price => 100.0
#    },
#    [3] {
#      :description => "some description 6",
#            :price => 100.0
#    }
#  ]
# }
```

Comment: Thank you! It's nice to know that you can delete the key you are grouping by!